# Select a images from a folder and then display it in a selectlist or just display it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi guys im really new at this!

I have been stuck here for along time. Please i really need your help. Thanks!

My question for you are. How can i display all of my images to a Selectlist or dropdownlist in MVC and then post it on the site? I got a database with PicID, PicTitle etc..

I want to display or show the images from that folder and then be enable to choose a picture and then display it in the view.

In my Create View i have:

```
<h2>Create</h2>
```

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Picture</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PicTitle)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PicTitle)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PicTitle)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PicUrl)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.Action(Model.PicID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PicID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PicAltText)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PicAltText)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PicAltText)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PicDesc)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PicDesc)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PicDesc)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PicPrio)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PicPrio)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PicPrio)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CatID, "Category")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("CatID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CatID)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

And in my Controller:

```
        public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.CatID = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CatID", "CatName");
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Picture/Create



    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Picture picture, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var FileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", Guid.NewGuid(), file.ContentType);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images_upload"), FileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Pictures.AddObject(picture);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(db.Pictures, "PicID", "PicTitle", picture.PicID);
        return View(picture);
    }
```

Please help me and thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Change the SQL table to store the path of your images:

[image]

2) Create a **Model** where you retrieve the data from the picture table in SQL and populate a `SelectList` property(this will be used to display your images in the drop down list)

```
public class Image
{
    public SelectList ImageList { get; set; }

    public Image()
    {
        ImageList = GetImages();
    }

    public SelectList GetImages()
    {
        var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
        string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["imageConnection"].ConnectionString;

        using (var con = new SqlConnection(connection))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Picture", con))
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string title = reader[1] as string;
                    string imagePath = reader[2] as string;
                    list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = title, Value = imagePath });
                }
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        return new SelectList(list,"Value","Text");
    }
}
```

3) **Controller**:

```
public class ImagesController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult ShowImages()
    {
        Image image = new Image();
        return View(image);
    }
}
```

4) **View**:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Image

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Images";
}

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ImageList").change(function () {
            var imagePath = $("#ImageList").val();
            $("#image").attr('src', imagePath)
        });
        $("#ImageList").trigger('change');
    });
</script>
@Html.DropDownList("ImageList")
<img alt="image" id="image" style="width:200px;height:200px;" />
```

**Output:**

[image]

If you don't get it right I've uploaded a sample project on [Google Drive](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0iPiW5jXDdPNmxITEJQRG1zTjg/edit?usp=sharing) (just click File->Download)

Comment: Hi Deni and thanks for the help. 

Im getting " There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'ImageList'. What can be the problem?

Comment: There is no IEnumerable<SelectListItem> in the answer I've provided, please copy the code exactly as is.If you're still having issues download the sample project

Comment: Yes its works fine but when i try to put in my project im getting that error. :(